# Re-Expressing Quantity Using Different Set of Variables

Tags: equation-solving, coordinate-transformation

I have a quantity `ds2` which is expressed in term of a set of 5 variables (let's call them `t, r, θ, φ, ψ`). I have 5 equations (let’s label them `eqi` where `i`=1, 2..5) relating those variables to another set of variables (let’s those `T, y, Θ, Φ, Ψ`). How can I express my original quantity solely using the second set?

I have tried the following pieces of code:

1. Solve

```
Solve[{ds2==bla bla bla, eq1 && eq2 && eq3 && eq4 && eq5}, ds2, {T, y, Θ, Φ, Ψ}, Reals]
-> "Solve: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve."
```

2. Eliminate

```
Eliminate[{ds2= bla bla bla, eq1, eq2,eq3, eq4, eq5}, {T, y, Θ, Φ, Ψ}]
-> "Eliminate: Inverse functions are being used by Eliminate, so some solutions may not be found; 
use Reduce for complete solution information."
```

Edit: Below are the explicit quantites/equations

```
eq1 = Xi[a] y^2 Sin[Θ]^2 == (r^2 + a^2) Sin[θ]^2;
eq2 = Φ == φ + a t/l^2;
eq3 = T == t;
eq4 = Xi[b] y^2 Cos[Θ]^2 == (r^2 + b^2) Cos[θ]^2;
eq5 = Ψ == ψ + b t/l^2;

ds2 = Sin[Θ]^2;
```

The actual `ds` is much more complicated, but even this simple case does not work and give the aforementioned error messages.

Comment: Without the actual equations, it's hard to say anything useful.

Comment: @J.M. I thought there was a general method for doing this procedure regardless. Isn’t there?

Comment: If the set of equations are not algebraic (like yours), there isn't. Also, `D[]` is reserved for the derivative, so don't use it here.

Comment: @J.M. first of, thank you very much so far. I have updates `ds2` with a much simpler case however. Could you let me know what I could do in this case if you know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eq1 = Xi[a] y^2 Sin[Θ]^2 == (r^2 + a^2) Sin[θ]^2;
eq2 = Φ == φ + a t/l^2;
eq3 = T == t;
eq4 = Xi[b] y^2 Cos[Θ]^2 == (r^2 + b^2) Cos[θ]^2;
eq5 = Ψ == ψ + b t/l^2;
```

Without some form of constraints there are many alternatives for `{t, r, θ, φ, ψ}`in terms of `{T, y, Θ, Φ, Ψ}`

```
sol = (Solve[
     eq1 && eq2 && eq3 && eq4 && eq5,
     {t, r, θ, φ, ψ}] // Simplify);

Length@sol

(* 16 *)
```

Further, the solutions for `θ` are periodic

```
Cases[sol, (var_ -> c_ConditionalExpression) :> {var, c[[-1]]}, 
  Infinity] // Union

(* {{θ, C[1] ∈ Integers}} *)
```

Since your `ds2` is **initially** supposed to be in terms of `{t, r, θ, φ, ψ}` I changed its definition. Looking at the first solution and with `C[1] == 0`

```
ds2 = Sin[θ]^2 /. sol[[1]] /. C[1] -> 0 // Simplify

(* (1/(2 (a^2 - b^2)))(a^2 - b^2 + y^2 Sin[Θ]^2 Xi[a] + 
  y^2 Cos[Θ]^2 Xi[
    b] - √(4 (a^2 - b^2) y^2 Cos[Θ]^2 Xi[b] + (-a^2 + 
       b^2 + y^2 Sin[Θ]^2 Xi[a] + 
       y^2 Cos[Θ]^2 Xi[b])^2)) *)
```